# error while adding google places sdk for Android[Cause: duplicate entry: com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedAppGlideModule.class]

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, android-glide, google-places

when we tried to add new google places SDK, we encountered an error while generating build,

> Cause: duplicate entry: com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedAppGlideModule.class

libraries used in my project:

- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
- compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0
- com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Glide setup and configuration](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#avoid-appglidemodule-in-libraries)
   Applications integrating Glide must add exactly one AppGlideModule implementation

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
 }

Finally, you should keep AppGlideModule implementations in your proguard.cfg:

 -keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
 -keep class com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl
```